# is it possible to do multiple counts in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

is it possible to do multiple counts in the same query in sql/sas? I am doing the following and obviously I am getting a response at the sku level as that is the most detailed level. I would like to see the counts of all of these individually distinct to issuance offer code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t1.ISSUANCE_OFFER_CODE,
   (COUNT(t1.SKU)) AS COUNT_of_SKU,
   (COUNT(t1.ASSORTMENT)) AS COUNT_of_ASSORTMENT,
   (COUNT(t1.PRODUCT_GROUP)) AS COUNT_of_PRODUCT_GROUP,
   (COUNT(t1.DIVISION_NAME))
FROM WORK.OFFERS t1
GROUP BY t1.ISSUANCE_OFFER_CODE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `DISTINCT` to the `COUNT`s:

```
SELECT

t1.ISSUANCE_OFFER_CODE,
(COUNT(t1.SKU)) AS COUNT_of_SKU,
(COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ASSORTMENT)) AS COUNT_of_ASSORTMENT,
(COUNT(DISTINCT t1.PRODUCT_GROUP)) AS COUNT_of_PRODUCT_GROUP, 
(COUNT(DISTINCT t1.DIVISION_NAME))

FROM WORK.OFFERS t1

GROUP BY t1.ISSUANCE_OFFER_CODE;
```

Comment: You can also use `CASE` inside the `COUNT` to filter the element you want to count